# XPath expression to ignore the child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <folder>
      <TestOne>F</TestOne>
      <TestTwo>01</TestTwo>
      <case>
         <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840</CRDATTIM>
         <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
      </case>
      <case>
         <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840</CRDATTIM>
         <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
      </case>
   </folder>
</response>
```

I need the XPath expression to read the nodes and their values immediately under the `<folder>` tag. I don't require the child nodes information. I mean, my extracted info should look like below:

```
<folder>
<TestOne>F</TestOne>
<TestTwo>01</TestTwo>
<folder>
```

Here the tags names listed under `<folder>`i.e `<TestOne>, <TestTwo>` are dynamic.

Is there any way to derive an XPath expression for above requirement? Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say '...to read the attributes and their values...', but which attributes? there are only nodes in your xml...

Comment: Sorry..I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is a way to select particular nodes out of an XML tree, but on its own it can't change the content of any of those nodes.  If you use an expression to select the `folder` element

```
/response/folder
```

then you'll get the whole of that element, including the `case` children.  You could select just the "leaf" elements under `folder` using

```
/response/folder/*[not(*)]
```

which would give you a node set containing two elements (the `TestOne` and the `TestTwo`), but assembling those two elements into a *new* `folder` element is not something XPath can do for you.  You'll have to do that yourself using whatever facilities are provided by the language/tool you're using to evaluate the XPath expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a template that will output only direct childs of a `<folder>` node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/response/folder">
        <folder>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="childs"/>
        </folder>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="childs">
        <xsl:if test="count(./text()) = 1">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're just after the xpath to get all those nodes within your folder node:

```
/response/folder/node()[count(text()) = 1]
```

Comment: The keyword here is XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `count` method?

```
/response/folder/*[count(*)=0]
```